# Node child_process slow when running jar

Tags: node.js, jar, child-process

So I'm trying to run a jar (pmd) through node.

When I run a command in my terminal it responds with almost no latency.

However, when I the same command with node it take 20-30 seconds to respond.

Any ideas why this is happening?  Is this expected behavior with running jars in node?

Answer (score 0):

turns out it wasn't the jar that was slowing it down but the `.sh` file I was calling that was running the jar.  I'm not sure why this would slow it down, but calling the jar directly sped things up greatly.